# Where to find details for the API of Context in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I coded some routine Hadoop MapReduce jobs, and thus call the `context.write()` method just based on some examples from the given Apache Hadoop source code. But such kinda copy doesn't help me understand the Hadoop API deeper.

Therefore, recently I started to read the Hadoop API document (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/) more carefully and try to figure out are there any other methods in Context except for `context.write()`. For instance, in the `teragen` example, `context.getCounter()` is used.

But to my surprise, I couldn't find the `Context` class documentation at all from the link above.

Where can i find the documentation for the `Context` class in hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

You can start to work out whats going on if you dig into the standard [Mapper class](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.java) source (around line 106).

```
public abstract class Context
    implements MapContext<KEYIN,VALUEIN,KEYOUT,VALUEOUT> {
}
```

So this is just an `abstract class` which implements the `MapContext` interface found [here](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/MapContext.java) ([Javadoc link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/MapContext.html)).

The concrete implementation is `MapContextImpl` found [here](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/task/MapContextImpl.java).

It looks like the `ContextFactory` ([source](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/ContextFactory.java)) is responsible for creating the different implementations of Context.